# Snowflake Return Data From Modified Rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In PostgreSQL, there is a concept to return the data modified by the query in the same query.

```
UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.10
  WHERE price <= 99.99
  RETURNING name, price AS new_price;
```

Above is the sample query that returns the name and price after the update is completed.

Is there any concept available in Snowflake as listed above?

I am trying to do the following,

- Update and get the same record
- Avoid collision on updates between the process.

Reference for PostgreSQL : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/dml-returning.html

Comment: Per the example: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/update.html#examples the result of an update will show number of rows changed however you can preview the data that changed, it uses less compute credits.

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice feature.  Snowflake doesn't have that, but you could open a transaction and do a select and then the update, to the same effect.  However if your objective is to log changes you might want to check out change tracking with [Table Streams](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/streams.html) -- currently in preview.

Comment: Hi @waldente, I will have two applications running independently and each needs to get the task based on the status. If one application takes one record those records should not be used by another application.


In pgsql, We have avoided the collision by using the above-mentioned method. 


is there any other alternative approach to achieve this with Snowflake?

Comment: Hi @devanathan.  One solution is to algorithmically split the work, for example, by having one application process even transactions and the other odd.  This is ideal.  Another approach would be to add a column say called KEY.  Amend your UPDATE to also set the KEY to timestamp+app-name.  Use the key to retrieve the modified rows.  Or, lastly, if you can't add columns to the table, create a "lock table" with a single row, and have both apps try to update the row inside a transaction.  One will block until the other commits.  (Least ideal!)

Comment: Thanks @waldente for the valuable suggestion. I have multiple workers and workers are created dynamically.

Comment: Hmm...Would a message queue be a fit here?  That could avoid contention by having one node feed the workers.  If the probability of contention is low, you might consider optimistic locking.  Lastly you could handle the locking outside of Snowflake.  Keep in mind that Snowflake it not optimized for intensive transactional operations.

Comment: yes, @waldente.  I am trying to handle the locking strategy outside the database probably Redis.